# Created kubeconfig file but only able to access default namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I used below file to create service account

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: sa-reader
  namespace: default

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  annotations:
    rbac.authorization.kubernetes.io/autoupdate: "true"
  name: reader-cr
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - apps
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: read-only-rb
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: sa-reader
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: reader-cr
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

The kubeconfig I created is something similar

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
preferences: {}

clusters:
- name: qa
  cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: ca
    server: https:/<server>:443

users:
- name: sa-reader
  user:
    as-user-extra: {}
    token: <token>

contexts:
- name: qa
  context:
    cluster: qa
    user: sa-reader
    namespace: default

current-context: qa
```

With this kubeconfig file, I am able to access resources in the default namespace but not any other namespace. How to access resources in other namespaces as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can operate on a namespace explicitly by using the `-n` (`--namespace`) option to `kubectl`:

```
$ kubectl -n my-other-namespace get pod
```

Or by changing your default namespace with the `kubectl config` command:

```
$ kubectl config set-context --current --namespace my-other-namespace
```

With the above command, all future invocations of `kubectl` will assume the `my-other-namespace` namespace.

Comment: Hope the above information is helpful and were you able to solve your issue, if yes please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

An empty `namespace` in `metadata`, defaults to `namespace: default` and so, your `RoleBinding` is only applied to the `default` namespace.

See [ObjectMeta](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.23/#objectmeta-v1-meta).

I suspect (!) you need to apply to `RoleBinding` to each of the namespaces in which you want the Service Account to be permitted.

Comment: But if I created more NS in the future. Isn't it going to create a problem if I have to create rolebinding every time